# issues to add the scroll bar in phonegap android

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, scrollbar

I created a div dynamically, I tried to add the scroll bar by using iscroll js.

But my application raised an error.

Can anybody guide me?

```
// here to add scroll bar 

function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { scrollbarClass: 'myScrollbar' });
}
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

// here i created a div dynamically

$results_list = $('<div id="wrapper" class="'+options.resultsClass+'" style="width:92%;height:10%;overflow:auto;position:absolute;"></div>').hide();//here i need to add scroll bar?
doIscrollRefresh();
```

**Error message**

`TypeError: Result of expression 'that.wrapper' [null] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www1/iscroll.js:60`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below div in your code and check it:

```
<div style="width:100%; float:left;  overflow-x:scroll;  padding-top:260px;>
  </div>
```